# I deleted path in environment variable and add help new

Tags: windows-7

I installed min gw compiler for my c programming and I am a beginner then I go to the environment variable and their in path I just deleted the last path of the system and added a new path of min gw compiler and saved it what should I do It's Windows 7 help pls from factory reset

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Without knowing what the last path was, its impossible to help you. But it should not seriously break windows without, and if you get an error message, you can google to solve it, which will tell you what you need to add to the path again

Comment: Windows 7 help pls from factory reset  ......  Out of support long ago and will not update. You are probably missing numerous updates.

Comment: You probably don't need a factory reset.  Path is no biggie to fix.  If you do want a factory reset for windows 7.. you will either need to re-install from windows 7 ISO (USB or DVD) or if you have an OEM machine like Dell or HP, the reset is available at boot time via a hidden partition (assuming you didn't delete it). Instructions for this vary by brand.  As mentioned, you probably should not be using 7 but that is up to you.  If you can't run an upgraded windows, perhaps Linux would be a good choice for what you are using the machine for.